# Ajax: on success replace string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have an Ajax function that updates some data on click. I send the variables on post, as function parameters. On the other side, I parse an array of variables and apply the function on each of them. Here is my code:

```
function vote(user, picture){
  var data = {
    "user": user,
    "picture": picture
  };
  var url = 'vote_up.php';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $('a#voteaza').replaceWith('<span style="color:#abb4c9; font-size: 15px;"> </span>');
      $('#changeNumber').html(parseInt($('#changeNumber').html(), 10)+1);
    }
  });
}
```

And the PHP:

```
foreach($photos['data'] as $photo) {
  $a = end(explode( '/',$photo['source']));
  <a href="#" id="voteaza" name = "<?php echo $a; ?>" style="color:#abb4c9; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; " onclick="vote('<?php echo $user ?>', '<?php echo $a ?>');">Voteaza</a> <br /> <span style="color:#abb4c9; font-size: 13px;" id="changeNumber"> <?php echo no_votes($a); ?> Voturi </span>
```

The problem is that, on success, the jquery

```
$('a#voteaza').replaceWith('<span style="color:#abb4c9; font-size: 15px;"> Vote! </span>');
$('#changeNumber').html(parseInt($('#changeNumber').html(), 10)+1);
```

Replaces all the 'voteaza' ids with the 'Vote' string, and increments all the 'changenumber' id fields. But I want the success function to execute only for the currently Ajax updated `<a name` element.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *all* the `voteaza`?  There can only be one

Comment: Element IDs must be unique. Use classes instead of IDs for non-unique values.

Comment: You should not have multiple fields with the same ID in your HTML. Try using a class definition.

Comment: Edited, to explain all the 'voteaza'.

Comment: So, if a use a class .voteaza instead of an id #voteaza it will work?

Comment: **Replaces all the 'voteaza' ids** ?? just saying same as above id must be unique just validate you code in w3c and it will give you error

Comment: since you are using same id, thats why all the 'voteaza' ids are getting replaced. Use unique id and you will have your code working fine:)

Comment: cool Sankalp, i'll try it right away

Comment: still, if i use different ids, how will i call $('a#voteaza') ? (if i won't know the current id, because it is dynamic?)

Comment: you said you update data on click..Probably you can get id from that click

Comment: Can you select with the parent element ie $("#parent a").html ....

Comment: true. i'll try and post the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOUR ID SHOULD BE UNIQUE IN PAGE. YOU CAN NOT GIVE SAME ID TWICE IN PAGE : You can see you are calling id in foreach and all have same value.

Try this i ma not sure if this works. You can make it work this way.

```
vote(this,'<?php echo $user ?>', '<?php echo $a ?>')

function vote(test,user, picture){

$(test).replaceWith('<span style="color:#abb4c9; font-size: 15px;"> Vote! </span>');
```